# Evaluating integral using Cauchy's integral formula singularities

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have the following question. I know Cauchy's integral formula but I am facing an exercise where I have singularities and I can not solve it directly. The problem is to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{C^{+}} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2(z^2+1)}dz$$
with $C\equiv|z|=2$ and it is clear that $i,-i$ and $0$ are singularities so I can not apply directly the theorem. I am lost with this exercise.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need Residue Theorem for this.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? It is my first time facing this kind of exercises

Comment: If you want to use Cauchy's formula, you should use partial fraction decomposition

Comment: I dont know how to compute this fraction decomposition

Answer (score 1):

We can partial fraction decompose the integrand since

$$\frac{1}{z^2(z^2+1)} = \frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{2i} \frac{1}{z-i} + \frac{1}{2i} \frac{1}{z+i}$$

which means we get that the original integral is equal to

$$I = \oint_{|z|=2} \frac{\sin z}{z^2}\:dz - \frac{1}{2i}\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{\sin z}{z-i}\:dz + \frac{1}{2i}\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{\sin z}{z+i}\:dz$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{2\pi i\sin z}{z^2}\:dz - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{\pi\sin z}{z-i}\:dz + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{\pi\sin z}{z+i}\:dz$$

$$ = (2\pi i \sin z)' \Bigr|_{z=0} - \pi \sin i + \pi \sin (-i) = 2\pi i -2\pi \sin i$$

entirely by Cauchy's integral formulae, not the residue theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cauchy integral formula.

To evaluate a given pole rewrite the expression as $\frac {g(z)}{z-a}$ and evaluate at $a$

e.g. to evaluate at the pole $z = i$

$\oint \frac {\sin z}{z^2(z^2+1)} = \oint \frac {\frac {\sin z}{z^2(z+i)}}{(z-i)} = 2\pi i \left(\frac {\sin z}{z^2(z+i)}\
\right)|_{z=i} = 2\pi i \frac {\sin i}{-2i} = -\pi \sin i = -\pi i\sinh 1$

Do the same at the other two poles.

Answer (score 0):

The function has three simple poles at $0,i$ and $-i$. The residue at a simple pole $a$ is equal to  $\lim_{z \to a} (z-a)f(z)$. I will let you calculate the residues. You should get the residues as $1$, $\frac 1 2 i\sin i$ and $\frac 1 2 i\sin i$. So the given integral equals $2 \pi i(1+\sin i)$

Comment: Umm but $z=0$ is a pole of order 2

Comment: It is not. remember that $\frac {\sin  z} z \to 1$ as $z \to 0$. So one power $z$ cancels with $\sin z$.